# Heroku ignores system.properties and java.runtime.version=11

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, heroku-cli, java-11

I'm trying to deploy a runnable Spring Boot jar via Heroku CLI.

On 2018-11-06 it was sufficient to define the `java.runtime.version=11` Config Var in the application settings.

Since 2018-11-07 Heroku ignores it and uses the default 1.8 Java. I have also pushed the `system.properties` file with content `java.runtime.version=11`, but it gets ignored either.

Does anybody have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have commited changes to the **master** branch of your local git repository before pushing to Heroku.

Comment: same problem, heroku ignores it for some reason